# Group of Hermitian and Unitary matrices

Tags: group-theory, matrices, representation-theory

This question is continuation of an earlier question asked  in [Matrices which are both unitary and Hermitian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57148/matrices-which-are-both-unitary-and-hermitian)

Consider the unitary group $U(n^2)$ and consider the 
subset $R$ of Hermitian Unitary matrices. We want to find
different conjugacy classes of $R$ by the subgroup action of
$U(n)\otimes U(n)$, i.e. $R_1$ ~ $R_2$ iff $\exists U\otimes V$
such that $R_1=U\otimes V R_2 U^*\otimes V^*$. Let 
$\mathcal{R}$ be the set of such conjugacy classes. My 
question is, how much is known about thee structure of $\mathcal{R}$, i.e. 
whether this is finite, or finitely generated or isomorphic  to some known object.  Also, can someone
suggest any paper/article discussing the above problem.

Comment: Are you sure $R$ is a subgroup?

Comment: @Jason DeVito: My mistake. If $R$ is a subgroup, then it has to be commutative, which need not be the case. I have changed the question accordingly considering $R$ as a subset.

Comment: What's the motivation to restrict to $U\otimes U$?

Comment: @draks Thanks for asking. In quantum mechanics $U\otimes V$ are called local unitary. One use of them is they can not create or destroy quantum entanglement. The $R$ mentioned above is also an observable, and I want to see how many of them are conjugate to each other by the above relation.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like [this](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/quant-ph/0610061)...