# Are there Hermitian Unitary matrices U and V generating $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ast \mathbb{Z}/2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Are there involutory unitary matrices U and V such that the group generated by U and V is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ast \mathbb{Z}/2$?   If so, how many such pairs of matrices are there?  Is there a known way to classify or at least generate examples of such pairs?  Alternatively, can you prove no such pairs exist?

I am mostly interested in the case where U and V are $N \times N$ matrices with $N = 2^n$ for positive integers $n$, but would also be interested in any special cases.

Thoughts so far:  If U and V are involutions and unitary, then each must be Hermitian also.  Thus, each of U and V must be a matrix with all eigenvalues equal to $\pm 1$.

Also, since $\langle U, V \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \ast \mathbb{Z}/2$ and since U and V are involutions, $UVUV = UVU^{-1}V^{-1} = [U,V] \neq I$, so U and V cannot commute, and in fact they also cannot anticommute since that would mean $[U,V]^2 = I$, which would again fail our requirements.

Another line of thinking comes from an answer to this question ([Matrices which are both unitary and Hermitian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57148/matrices-which-are-both-unitary-and-hermitian)) which states that a matrix U is Hermitian and Unitary if and only if $U = 2P - I$, for some orthogonal projection $P$.  I'm not sure if this helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just take $U$ and $V$ to be two real orthogonal reflections about lines through the origin such that the angle between them is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. Then $UV$ has infinite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all pairs of involutions satisfy this property.

Unitary involutions are in correspondence with subspaces, so the space of pairs $(U,V)$ (or representations of $\mathbb Z/2 *\mathbb Z/2$) is a disjoint union of products of Grassmannians, of course.

The condition that $U,V$ determine a *faithful* representation of $\mathbb Z/2*\mathbb Z/2$ is equivalent to $\langle UV\rangle \cong \mathbb Z$. Another way to see this condition is to remove the pairs $(U,V)$ such that $(UV)^n = I$ for each $n$. Since the matrix equation is just a set of polynomial equations in the coefficients of the matrices, for fixed $n$ it defines a subvariety. On the $G_\delta$ set away from the countable union of these subvarieties, the condition is true. This is what algebraic geometers call a "very generic property."

We're over an uncountable base field, so a very generic property always holds on a non-empty set. In more analytic language, a subvariety has measure 0, so by subadditivity their countable union also has measure zero. Thus the property holds almost everywhere.

Comment: Are you taking the correspondence between unitary involutions and subspaces to be via the $U = 2P - I$ decomposition I mentioned above?

Comment: @user334137 Yes, $U$ corresponds to the image of $P$.