# Matrices that are simultaneously Hermitian and unitary

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

My quantum mechanics professor was discussing the properties of Pauli matrices, their being both Hermitian and unitary. Then he made a remark that it is not possible to find three $n \times n$ matrices, where $n > 2$, that are simultaneously Hermitian and unitary. Can someone please explain or give a hint as to why this has to be true?

Comment: Integral multiples of the identity are not unitary (unless the integer multiplier is $\pm1$).

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: It doesn't seem right to me, but maybe your prof had some additional property in mind (or mentioned some additional property which escaped your attention). Anyway, you might find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57148/matrices-which-are-both-unitary-and-hermitian enlightening.

Comment: Why three matrices? I strongly suspect he was talking about three such matrices satisfying the su(2) algebra, spin matrix irreps, in which case he'd be right, as per the irreducible representation structure of spin.

Comment: What does "simultaneously" mean in your context?

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments and the answer, Kashish?

Comment: He said that the statement was incorrect and that he meant that spins higher than 1/2 have spin observable matrices hermitian but not unitary.

Answer (score 2):

Three of the four [Dirac matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)
$$
\gamma^1=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad \gamma^2=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&-i\\0&0&i&0\\0&i&0&0\\-i&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad \gamma^3=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\\-1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{matrix}\right)
$$
are obviously anti-Hermitian and unitary. Therefore, their multiples with $\pm i$ are Hermitian and unitary.